# Halloween Sale | Hackerrank

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, counting

You wish to buy video games from the famous online video game store Mist.

Usually, all games are sold at the same price,  dollars. However, they are planning to have the seasonal Halloween Sale next month in which you can buy games at a cheaper price. Specifically, the first game you buy during the sale will be sold at  dollars, but every subsequent game you buy will be sold at exactly  dollars less than the cost of the previous one you bought. This will continue until the cost becomes less than or equal to  dollars, after which every game you buy will cost  dollars each.

For example, if ,  and , then the following are the costs of the first  games you buy, in order:

You have  dollars in your Mist wallet. How many games can you buy during the Halloween Sale?

My code is this, I'd like to know why this fails for 11/52 test cases.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ct=0,i,p,d,m,s;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&p,&d,&m,&s);
    i=p;
    while(i<s)
    {
        if(p-d>m) p-=d;
        else p=m;
        i+=p;
        ct+=1;
    }
    printf("%d",ct);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some texts are missing from problem definition. Must improve your copy-paste skills.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `ct` as long as you have money left, but if the money you have left won't cover the cost of the game, then you can't buy it.

Answer (score 0):

@Dialecticus is right. You are missing critical information to your question. While I have solved this same [Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/halloween-sale/problem) and passed all test case. I will only share pseudo code because my solution was in JS not C++.

```
counter = 0; // sales counter

// we still have enough money for a normal and a discounted game
while s >= m && s >= p

    // Apply discount after one game
    if counter > 0
        p = the larger price between the discounted price & min price       

    // deduct price from wallet
    s -= p;

    // record the sale
    counter++

return counter
```

I decided to include the actual JS code, maybe you could transpile it.

```
let counter = 0;
while(s >= m && s >= p) {
    p = counter > 0 ? Math.max(p - d, m) : p;
    s -= p;
    counter++;
}
return counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a formula instead? Something like:

```c
if (p > s)
  return 0;

int t = min(
  ceil((p - m) / (float)d),
  floor((sqrt(8 * ceil((s - p) / (float)d) + 1) - 1) / 2)
);

return t + floor((s - (p * t - d * t * (t - 1) / 2)) / m);
```